# Does Azure B2B using a Google ID (e.g. Federation) still require an object to be created in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I saw a post today on linkedIN to say Azure B2B now accepts Google IDs (e.g. people with a Gmail account)
It said this is achieved via Federation, (using google as the identity provider)

As far as I am aware you have been able to do this for a while (or was that because it was in public preview), whereby someone could enter their gmail account but in the background (after the simple on boarding process was completed) this gmail account is linked to a place holder Azure AD account (represented by a GUID). 
So in the announcement of Azure AD now accepts google IDs, is this the case where a preview service is now main stream ? or is this something new?

My main question is below

As far as I understand federation (please correct me if I am wrong) although your own Identity provider together with your own STS (secure token service, which is trusted by the replying party) provides you with a token (signed SAML/JWT) with is then presented to the replying parties STS (which then creates is own token from the information in the token you provided), you still need an instance of an object (user/group etc) in the Replaying parties system to check if said instance is allowed access to a resource based on the token (looking at the ACL on the resource and the information in the token). So although the replying party does not need to maintain the users password to authenticate them   (done by the trusted Identity Provider) **an instance of an object still needs to be created/exists on the Relaying Party system** (to match the token information e.g. group membership for example) to the ACL on the actual object trying to be accessed
is the above correct?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

A User is always created in Azure AD, as it is in this case as well.
This applies to users created in Azure AD, synced from on-prem AD, invited from other AAD tenants, personal MS accounts, and now Gmail accounts.

Before Google B2B, if you invited a Gmail user, a personal Microsoft account would be created for them in the background, which would then be added as a Guest in the AAD tenant.

Now if you enable Google B2B, when you invite a Gmail user, they'll log in on the Google login page instead of the AAD login page.
So now instead of creating an MS account invisibly, the Google account itself is added as a Guest User, and AAD relies on Google to authenticate the user.

Comment: Hello juunas, thank you for taking the time to reply, So when you say with the new B2B " the Google account itself is added as a Guest User" is this done automatically via a graph API (or similar API) so basically a guest user object is still added to your Azure AD tenant (so rights to apps can be assigned to said guest user), but this is not a Microsoft account (e.g. in the Microsoft's own tenant) but directly added to your tenant as a guest?  I appreciate your time, as I just want to understand

Comment: Inviting via portal or inviting via MS Graph API's invite endpoint leads to the same result, there will be a guest user in your AAD.

Comment: Thanks very much :) that is fantastic now I understand